# Nested functions in typescript gives errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am not sure how you are supposed to nest functions in TypeScript. I was doing it similar to Javascript and got a lot of errors.

I have this in my typescript file (this is basically the only thing there):

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    d3.csv('data/data.csv').then((data: Array<String> => {
      data.forEach(d:string =>{
        d.age = Number(d.age)
      })
    })
  }
```

And my data.csv file has this:

```
name,age
Lam,30
Peter,90
Aaron,2
Swizt,14
Irene,36
Travis, 55
```

I get errors such as

```
"Argument of type '(data: String[], { data, forEach }: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: DSVRowArray<string>) => any'.ts(2345)"
```

, and

```
"A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.ts(2371)"
```

Comment: your arrow function syntax is wrong, it should be `(arg: Type) => { ... }`, not `arg: Type => {...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you provided the wrong types for your callback function. `d3.csv` returns a `DSVRowArray<string>` not a `String[]`. You've also forgot to close the bracket after `.then((data: Array<String>` hence why `{ data, forEach }: any` is showing up in the argument list. `string` is also the wrong type for the `foreach` loop, it should be a `DSVRowString`.

Also, the compiler will prevent you from assigning a number value to a property of a `DSVRowString`, as the d3 devs have specified that only string properties are allowed. So if you want an object with number values you should create a new object.

You can define the `DSVRowArray<string>` and `DSVRowString` types in your callbacks but it's not necessary. The compiler already knows the types according to the type definitions provided by the d3 devs. So you can just exclude them, intellisense and tsc will infer the correct type.

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    d3.csv('data/data.csv').then((data) => {
      data.forEach((d) => {
        const convertedData = { age: Number(d['age']) };
      });
    });
  }
```

If you absolutely need to keep the same structure, you can just typecast the `DSVRowString` to `any`. This is just a way to make the compiler leave you alone. Not recommended though.

```js
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    d3.csv('data/data.csv').then((data) => {
      data.forEach((d: any) => {
        d.age = Number(d.age);
      });
    });
  }
```

There is also an overload for the csv function, where you can provide a function describing how to parse each row. In the below function `data` has the type `d3.DSVParsedArray<{age: number}>` which I get from intellisense after hovering over the variable.

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    d3.csv('data/data.csv', (d) => {
      return { age: Number(d['age']) };
    }).then((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```

Logging data gives me:

```json
Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
  0: Object { age: 30 }
  1: Object { age: 90 }
  2: Object { age: 2 }
  3: Object { age: 14 }
  4: Object { age: 36 }
  5: Object { age: 55 }
  columns: Array [ "name", "age" ]
  length: 6
  <prototype>: Array []
```

Which seems to just be an extension of `Array` with the added `columns` property.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this, and it gives me an error in my console:

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    d3.csv('data/data.csv', (d) => {
      return { age: Number(d['age']) };
    }).then((data) => console.log(data));
  }

I get this error: 

GET http://localhost:54468/data/data.csv 404 (Not Found)
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: 404 Not Found
Error: 404 Not Found

I tried a bunch of things including changing the path of the data/data.csv file, like ../data/data.csv or /data/data.csv and a lot of other stuff, but i dont know why i still get that error.

Comment: Put the file in the `assets` folder and use the path `assets/data.csv`. Angular runs from your compiled code within the `dist` folder, so you need to use paths relative to that. Alternatively you can add the `data` folder to the `assets` array located in `angular.json` and that folder will get transferred to `dist` with the same path excluding the `src` prefix. For example if you add `"src/app/data/data.csv"` to your `assets` array, the import path would be `"app/data/data.csv"`. You can always run `ng build` and open the `dist` folder to see the outcome of compilation.

Comment: Yep, That worked, thank you for much for your help!